# How to better store long cookies in requests?

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

I try to find a better way to store long cookie values. Now my code looks:

```
from requests import Response

    payload = {
        'controller': 'authentication',
        'email': 'test@test.com',
        'passwd': 'Password123!',
        'back': 'my-account'
    }

    cookies = {
        'PrestaShop-a30a9934ef476d11b6cc3c983616e364': 'P7Kc4TcNog6mDRClNOEM1NDmQeYtdl7weRvewlFukK64noiXir9OQ9%2FewhQGFb5n75AK763b88qG55DuAt%2BkPUdDQ7WF4HeFaeCp%2F1S5npTQ49aG1JumA%2FLnG89dBYc9Hu%2BJkxlmlxx5K1yGWrN9iPkgq9LEZ6TDhUJNmm6lAtYxYs%2Fsb8RIPVU3TTI0SbYQ0Mb9nhjDU2TNSqa0xc70vLiMfKU2Pcbri9oXzeGkWDQrnKAnxC3eM4bBR%2BZHAc1I71fg5XLQgSs23%2Bz%2FVJ4Co%2FVUjB0XvwKrjA%2F7bGHTrgbgJHb%2FdH4jAPPFPvuTCFjU78m2T9A%2F4P3Jz8Fi8N9G0mV3%2F2OnHuAWKBWOaUG5QTVPaUjVpk2sld%2BjFbElEBwy0OyspQIM1YX3%2B7Gg%2B47R0u%2BrK00U4%2BOZxtHNJvhccBU%3D000308; expires=Tue, 08-Dec-2020 15:49:40 GMT; path=/; domain=automationpractice.com; httponly'
    }

    requests.post('http://automationpractice.com/index.php', data=payload, cookies=cookies)
```

As you can see my cookie is really long, I tried to pass this cookie to POST request by request.Session() but it doesn't work for me, probably I do something wrong.

Do you know how to handle it to look better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about displaying the cookie string better, than this is a possibility:

```
import requests

payload = {
    'controller': 'authentication',
    'email': 'test@test.com',
    'passwd': 'Password123!',
    'back': 'my-account'
}

cookies = {
    'PrestaShop-a30a9934ef476d11b6cc3c983616e364': (
        'P7Kc4TcNog6mDRClNOEM1NDmQeYtdl7weRvewlFukK64noiXir9OQ9%2FewhQGFb5n75AK763b88qG'
        '55DuAt%2BkPUdDQ7WF4HeFaeCp%2F1S5npTQ49aG1JumA%2FLnG89dBYc9Hu%2BJkxlmlxx5K1yGWr'
        'N9iPkgq9LEZ6TDhUJNmm6lAtYxYs%2Fsb8RIPVU3TTI0SbYQ0Mb9nhjDU2TNSqa0xc70vLiMfKU2Pc'
        'bri9oXzeGkWDQrnKAnxC3eM4bBR%2BZHAc1I71fg5XLQgSs23%2Bz%2FVJ4Co%2FVUjB0XvwKrjA%2'
        'F7bGHTrgbgJHb%2FdH4jAPPFPvuTCFjU78m2T9A%2F4P3Jz8Fi8N9G0mV3%2F2OnHuAWKBWOaUG5QT'
        'VPaUjVpk2sld%2BjFbElEBwy0OyspQIM1YX3%2B7Gg%2B47R0u%2BrK00U4%2BOZxtHNJvhccBU%3D'
        '000308; expires=Tue, 08-Dec-2020 15:49:40 GMT; path=/; domain=automationpractice.com; httponly'
    )
}
requests.post('http://automationpractice.com/index.php', data=payload, cookies=cookies)
```

This way each line inside the parenthesis will become a single string.